# Mylyn in Eclipse - No Finish or Next?

Tags: eclipse, trac, mylyn

I've just installed Eclipse Indigo and noticed Mylyn was already installed.  I use Trac for my ticketing, and decided to enable Mylyn talking to Trac.

However, after I fill out all the details in Mylyn, and do the validation (which succeeds), the "Finish" or "next" buttons don't go active.

This screenshot shows a successful validation, but I can't complete:

http://www.homeport.org/~dbs/screenshots/cn/Add_Task_Repository...-20111120-203607.jpg

Comment: Maybe there an issue with the settings.  Have you tried the `Validate Settings` button?

Comment: Yes, he did, as hinted at least two times inside the question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the problem, so I'm a bit puzzled.  What version of the Trac connector are you using?  (There are many ways to find out, but probably the easiest is to go Help->Install New Software...->click on "What is already installed" and look for Mylyn Tasks Connector: Trac.)

One thing that looks strange to me in the screenshot is that the server doesn't start with "http://".  What happens if you put "http://" at the beginning?

If that doesn't fix it, I might be able to help by looking at your error log; if you can't attach it here, you can send it to support at tasktop dot com.  (Don't worry everybody, I won't take this discussion off into email and hide it from you all.)

-- 
Kaitlin Duck Sherwood
Software Engineer, Support and Community, Tasktop
http://tasktop.com

Comment: Hi folks, I don't know why I wasn't notified that people had tried to answer this question... Let me fill in some info...

Comment: DOH - looks like this interface takes _enter_ as 'post'.  So:



Mylyn task connector: 3.6.3.v20111026-0100

Adding 'http://' doesn't help :(

the .metadata/.log doesn't have anything dramatic in it.  Still want me to mail it?

Comment: Dave -- sorry, *I* didn't see that you had responded.  Yes, please send the .log file.  You can send it to support at tasktop dot com.

Answer (score 0):

@dave-shevett, have you checked `.log` for any traces that might help understand the cause?